# Why does potential gradient in a potentiometer wire depend only on driving cell

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, home-experiment, batteries

The title is pretty much self explanatory.I have done some calculations.
[image]
I am considering this circuit analogous to a potentiometer, where $E_1$ is my driving cell and $R_1$ and $R_2$ make up the wire.Still,the current in the potentiometer wire will depend on attached battery as I have derived.Why do we then define potential gradient with only driving cell in consideration.If Kirchoff law is used then what causes the null point? By this I mean we cannot consider a wire to be a potential source ,any external attachment to a wire carrying current will modify the original circuit so current will change through that portion of wire too.This whole business of potentiometer and potential gradient seems rubbish to me unless I dont know of yet another approximation case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question completely, but a potentiometer is merely a three terminal device which allows for the center terminal to divide the resistance of R1+R2 according to the setting of the knob.  The actual voltages and currents will indeed depend on the externally connected components.

Depending on how you wish to use the potentiometer, various approximations can make sense.  For example, if you are connected to a device with high relative resistance (say R3 >> R1+R2 in your diagram), then the voltage at the center terminal will essentially be that which is due to R1+R2 and the setting of the knob etc.

I hope this helps.